# Regular expression to match n consecutive capitalized words

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I am trying to capture n consecutive capitalized words. My current code is

```
n=5 
a='This is a Five Gram With Five Caps and it also contains a Two Gram'
re.findall(' ([A-Z]+[a-z|A-Z]* ){n}',a)
```

Which returns the following:

```
['Caps ']
```

It's identifying the fifth consecutive capitalized word, but I would like it to return the entire string of capitalized words. In other words:

```
[' Five Gram With Five Caps ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `|` doesn't act as an `OR` inside a character class. It'll match `|` literally. The other issue here is that `findall`'s behaviour is to return the match **unless** a group exists (although [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) doesn't really make this *clear*):

> The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups**

So this is why you're getting the result of the first capture group, which is the last uppercase-starting word of `Caps`.

The simple solution is to change your capturing group to a non-capturing group. I've also changed the space at the start to `\b` so as to not match an additional whitespace (which I presume you were planning on trimming anyway).

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsIwEEX3@Yohq0RoN@JGEBGh/kBBsLoY20oH8mISFBW/PaYKFw6Xc8IzTd4tcyYbPCfgUQiGTWHdexvIjIrl@aq2625XnS4dVq@ZC9Dv1UdqEUsr24kilCE0dB/hwGjhSGn63z2GotwAlABN9NB7l5Dc3LcP/8ulCEwuKa5v5AY0RkWtc/4C)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"\b(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]* ){5}")
s = "This is a Five Gram With Five Caps and it also contains a Two Gram"
print(r.findall(s))
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/i8VkMI/2)

```
\b(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]* ){5}
```

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]* ?){5}` Match the following exactly 5 times

  - `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase ASCII letter once
  - `[a-zA-Z]*` Match any ASCII letter any number of times
  - Match a space

Result: `['Five Gram With Five Caps ']`

Additionally, you may use the regex [`\b\[A-Z\]\[a-zA-Z\]*(?: \[A-Z\]\[a-zA-Z\]*){4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/i8VkMI/3) instead. This will allow matches at the start/end of the string as well as anywhere in the middle without grabbing extra whitespace. Another alternative may include [`(?:^|(?<= ))\[A-Z\]\[a-zA-Z\]*(?: \[A-Z\]\[a-zA-Z\]*){4}(?= |$)`](https://regex101.com/r/i8VkMI/4)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole pattern in a capturing group:

```
(([A-Z]+[a-z|A-Z]* ){5})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6v4lGD/1/)